# Why can't I break with a single line conditional?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.6. I noticed that the following is not allowed:

```
while something:

    # do something

    # This is an invalid syntax
    break if condition else pass
```

Since [conditional expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/1391441) are allowed since v2.5, why is this usage not permitted?

Comment: I'm gonna go with because `break` (and `pass`) are *statements*, not *expressions*.  A conditional expression is a compound expression that, like any expression, evaluates to a value.

Comment: `break` is a statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ternary operator require expressions while both `break` and `pass` are statements.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that `break` is a statement, not an expression. Python's developers explicitly decided that they didn't want Python to be an expression-based language, hence the syntax error with your construct. As @Dmitry points out, there is no way to avoid having a `break` statement.

Comment: Though if all you need to do is break then it's permissible (though of questionable style) to write `if condition: break` on a single line. At present, however, vertical whitespace doesn't appear to be in short supply.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
while something:

    if condition:
        break
    else:
        ...
```

Note ternary conditional operator does not work with python statements.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear on the other Python question. I didn't mean to imply you copied my answer, just that your answer came later than mine, and didn't bring any new value. Thank you for deleting it. Note that I didn't downvote your answer (that's why I left a comment), and downvoting my answer hurts your reputation more than mine. Best regards, Eric

Comment: @EricDuminil I provided my own code and did not look at other answers. there is no difference for me that they suppose. I think it is user prerogative to evaluate answers. I have canceled my downvote and vote up for you answer. Best Wishes, Dmitry.